# Use select inside 'filename' property of utl_file.fopen

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that extracts data from a view and stores it on disc in CSV format. I'd like a name of the file to contain the most recent timestamp from table MY_TIMESTAMPS. For now it looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure write_file is
    file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
begin
    file_handle := utl_file.fopen('CSV_DIR', 'EXPORT_ABC_'|| (select to_char(max(EVENT_TS)) from MY_TIMESTAMPS) ||'.csv', 'w', 32767);
    for x in (select * from V_MY_VIEW
    loop utl_file.put_line (file_handle, COL1|| ',' ||
                                        COL2|| ',' ||
                                        COL3|| ',' ||
                                        COL4);
    end loop;
    utl_file.fclose(file_handle);
end write_file;
```

The part with `(select to_char(max(EVENT_TS)) from MY_TIMESTAMPS)` throws an error. How can I set this dynamic filename property? Maybe write it to some variable at beginning of the procedure? I tried to use DEFINE, but this errors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just might declare a variable in order to use within your select statement with an `INTO` clause added such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCDURE write_file IS
  file_handle utl_file.file_type;
  v_event_ts  varchar2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT to_char(max(EVENT_TS)) INTO v_event_ts FROM my_timestamps;
  file_handle := utl_file.fopen('CSV_DIR', 'EXPORT_ABC_'||v_event_ts||'.csv', 'w', 32767);
    ......
```

*where an exception handling is not needed for that SELECT statement.*

Comment: Thanks, it's compiling, although when I try to execute procedure it throws error `ORA-01843: not a valid month`. Could this be related to data type that we declared? Could you please explain what `my_timestamps.event_ts%type` exactly mean?

Comment: Hi @Limak , excuse me, I fixed where If you directly used `SELECT max(EVENT_TS) INTO v_event_ts` without `to_char`conversion, you could use `my_timestamps.event_ts%type` which implies the type of event_ts column, probably datetime, without explicitly expressing the data type, but in your case, I need to use a string data type because of that conversion.